# converting AnyObject to Array list of Strings in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm new to swift and i'm extracting data from `Parse` database.
The data column is stored as array in the database
i managed to extract it as `AnyObject` and now i want to display each item. `AnyObject` is displaying as 1 entry instead of array list

```
class PeopleTable: UITableViewController {
//let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"
//var window: UIWindow?
//let emptyArray: [AnyObject] = []
var userFriends: [AnyObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    queryForTable()
    print(userFriends) 
}
func queryForTable() {
    let relationQuery = PFQuery(className:"User_info")

    relationQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo:"id123")

    var userfrnds =  try? relationQuery.findObjects()
    for eachFriend in userfrnds! {
        self.userFriends.append(eachFriend["friends"])
    }
}
```

`print(userFriends)`  command Out Put :

> ```
> [(
>     Rudzani,
>     Terrence,
>     Thendelano,
>     "Big-T",
>     Smallboy
> )]
> ```

i want the out put to be :

> ```
> Rudzani,
> Terrence,
> Thendelano,
> "Big-T",
> Smallboy
> ```

How do i convert `AnyObject` to `Array` list of Strings

Comment: maybe:   `print (join(", ", userFriends))`

Comment: not working, i get "Cannot convert value of type "String" to expected Argument type '[Any]'

Comment: have you tried changing `var userFriends: [AnyObject] = []` to `var userFriends: [String] = []` , and then make this line `self.userFriends.append(eachFriend["friends"] as String)`

Comment: Its not working. its throwing error on self.userFriends.append(eachFriend["friends"] as String)   Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x16cf178) to 'NSString' (0x1ad5454)

Comment: Ok i think you are rerieving the `array` so what you need to do is put that into a variable that can hold an array and then acces the values from that new array

Comment: have you tried responseObject as! [String] ?

Comment: @MikeG,Array list come back as one item from parse database

Comment: OhadM Yes i have tried it and it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userFriends` is an array in an array, the printed output is of type `[[String]]`.

```
var userFriends = []
```

Then get the inner array

```
let users = userFriends[0]
```

and join the items

```
let users = userFriends[0].joinWithSeparator(", ")
```

As the type is distinct, any further type casting is not needed.

Edit: You have probably to cast the type after retrieving the object

```
do {
  let userfrnds =  try relationQuery.findObjects()
  for eachFriend in userfrnds {
    self.userFriends.append(eachFriend["friends"] as! [String])
  }
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: i get "Value of type ''Any Object" has no member "JoinWithSeparator" error on 'let users = userFriends[0].joinWithSeparator(", ") ' line

Comment: You have to cast `AnyObject` to `[String]`

Comment: `let users = userFriends[0].joinWithSeparator(", ") as String` i get the same eroor''Any Object" has no member "JoinWithSeparator"

Comment: You have to cast the type after retrieving the object. I updated the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: `let userfrnds =  try relationQuery.findObjects() as! [[String:AnyObject]]` is throwing this error   ‘PFObject’  is not convertible to ’[[String : AnyObject]]'

Comment: Then delete that cast but keep the other.

Comment: i deleted the cast but it still give me 1 term not array e.g[(
    Rudzani,
    Terrence,
    Thendelano,
    "Big-T",
    Smallboy
)]

Comment: Yes, now add the line to join the elements.

Comment: `let relationQuery = PFQuery(className:"User_info")
    
        relationQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo:"id123")
    
        do {
            let userfrnds =  try relationQuery.findObjects()
            for eachFriend in userfrnds {
                self.userFriends.append(eachFriend["friends"])
                let users = userFriends[0].joinWithSeparator(", ")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }    }`   i get the same error''Any Object" has no member "JoinWithSeparator"

Comment: ` let query = PFQuery(className:"User_info")
        query.whereKey("userID", equalTo:"id123")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) friends.")
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        self.peoplelists = object["friends"] as! [String]
                        print(self.peoplelists)
                    } }` this works but its a backgronud query

Comment: Asynchronous queries are always preferable. Have you changed the type of `userFriends` in the declaration line?

Comment: @ vadian, Your first code was right except the array declaration. please edit it so that i can mark it correct  Array declaration must be `    var userFriends = []`  ` func queryForTable() {
        let relationQuery = PFQuery(className:"User_info")
        relationQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo:"id123")
    
        let userfrnds =  try? relationQuery.findObjects()
            for object in userfrnds! {
                self.userFriends = object["friends"] as! [String]
                print(self.userFriends)
            }
    }`

Comment: final working  code ` var userFriends = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        queryForTable()
        print(self.userFriends)
    }


        
    func queryForTable() {
        let relationQuery = PFQuery(className:"User_info")
        relationQuery.whereKey("userID", equalTo:"id123")
    
        let userfrnds =  try? relationQuery.findObjects()
            for object in userfrnds! {
                self.userFriends = object["friends"] as! [String]
            }
    }`

Comment: **Do not** use `try?` and in the next line the forced unwrapped `userfrnds!`. If an error occurs the app will crash. Use the `do - catch` block

Comment: now its working. i just don't know how to format the code that i posted